# How can I sum if statement matches?

Tags: linux, awk

I want to keep plusing an integer if statement is a match in if clauses.
Here's my code:

```
awk 'sum = 0; {if( $3 ~ "9/12") sum = sum + 1};END { print sum}'  /var/lab/lab2/rusiuot/stud2001
```

What could be the case that it's not working?

Comment: On every line of input, you assign `sum = 0` and then conditionally increment it to 1.  Don't assign on each line of input.

Comment: I think OP intended `BEGIN{sum=0}` ... not needed as that would be the default initial value in numeric context

Comment: @Sundeep it is needed with `END{print sum}` (as the OP has) to ensure numeric output even when `sum` is never incremented. Alternatively don't write the `BEGIN` statement and use `END{print sum+0}` instead.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask] if that's not clear and pay particular attention to the part about providing a [mcve] (as I see you've been told in previous questions). The more effort you put into asking a question the better chance you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
awk '($3 ~ "9/12") {sum += 1} END { print sum }' ...
```

The trick to writing awk code is to understand it's basic structure.

A awk program is a series of `pattern { action }` statements.  In this case, the pattern you are interested in is that the third field looks like `"9/12"` and the action is to increment a number.  `BEGIN` and `END` are special patterns that are executed before any processing and after all processing.

Each line is passed through the series of patterns one at a time.  If a pattern matches, then the action is executed.  It can transform the input stream before the following patterns are matched.  You can also use the `next` statement to skip processing of the remaining patterns.

I highly recommend reading [awk(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) and [The AWK Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020107981X) if you are interesting in understanding awk in more detail.

Comment: `print sum+0` to assure numeric output even when the regexp comparison never succeeds. FYI `sum++` works in place of `sum +=  1` and you don't need parens around the regexp comparison so it could be a little briefer: `awk '$3 ~ "9/12"{ sum++ } END{ print sum+0 }'`. Do not bother to read The AWK Programming Language as it's 20+ years out of date - read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins instead.